# How to speed up this python function with numba?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numba

I'm trying to speed up this python function:

```py
def twoFreq_orig(z, source_z, num, den, matrix, e):
    Z1, Z2 = np.meshgrid(source_z, np.conj(z))
    Z1 **= num
    Z2 **= den - 1
    M = (e ** ((num + den - 2) / 2.0)) * Z1 * Z2
    return np.sum(matrix * M, 1)
```

where `z` and `source_z` are `np.ndarray` (1d, `dtype=np.complex128`), `num` and `den` are `np.ndarray` (2d, `dtype=np.float64`), `matrix` is a `np.ndarray` (2d, `dtype=np.complex128`) and `e` is a `np.float64`.

I don't have much experience with [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), but after reading some tutorials, I came up with this implementation:

```py
@nb.jit(nb.f8[:](nb.c16[:], nb.c16[:], nb.f8[:, :], nb.f8[:, :], nb.c16[:, :], nb.f8))
def twoFreq(z, source_z, num, den, matrix, e):
    N1, N2 = len(z), len(source_z)
    out = np.zeros(N1)
    for r in xrange(N1):
        tmp = 0
        for c in xrange(N2):
            n, d = num[r, c], den[r, c] - 1
            z1 = source_z[c] ** n
            z2 = z[r] ** d
            tmp += matrix[r, c] * e ** ((n + d - 1) / 2.0) * z1 * z2
        out[r] = tmp
    return out
```

Unfortunatelly, instead of a speedup, the Numba implementation is several times slower than the original. I can't figure out how to properly use Numba. Any Numba gurus out there than can give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't think there is much you can do to speedup your numba function without having some more insights into the properties of your arrays (is there some mathematical tricks to get some calculations done more quickly).

But I noticed one error: you didn't conjugate your array in the numba version for example and I edited some lines to make it more streamline (some of which might only be taste). I've included comments on the appropriate places:

```
@nb.njit
def twoFreq(z, source_z, num, den, matrix, e):
    #Replace z with conjugate of z (otherwise the result is wrong!)
    z = np.conj(z)
    # Size instead of len() don't know if it actually makes a difference but it's cleaner
    N1, N2 = z.size, source_z.size
    # Must be zeros_like otherwise you create a float array where you want a complex one
    out = np.zeros_like(z)
    # I'm using python 3 so you need to replace this by xrange later
    for r in range(N1):
        for c in range(N2):
            n, d = num[r, c], den[r, c] - 1
            z1 = source_z[c] ** n
            z2 = z[r] ** d
            # Multiply with 0.5 instead of dividing by 2
            # Work on the out array directly instead of a tmp variable
            out[r] += matrix[r, c] * e ** ((n + d - 1) * 0.5) * z1 * z2
    return out

def twoFreq_orig(z, source_z, num, den, matrix, e):
    Z1, Z2 = np.meshgrid(source_z, np.conj(z))
    Z1 **= num
    Z2 **= den - 1
    M = (e ** ((num + den - 2) / 2.0)) * Z1 * Z2
    return np.sum(matrix * M, 1)


numb = 1000
z = np.random.uniform(0,1,numb) + 1j*np.random.uniform(0,1,numb)
source_z = np.random.uniform(0,10,numb) + 1j*np.random.uniform(0,1,numb)
num = np.random.uniform(0,1,(numb,numb))
den = np.random.uniform(0,1,(numb,numb))
matrix = np.random.uniform(0,1,(numb,numb)) + 1j*np.random.uniform(0,1,(numb, numb))
e = 5.5

# This failed for your initial version:
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(twoFreq(z, source_z, num, den, matrix, e),
                                     twoFreq_orig(z, source_z, num, den, matrix, e))
```

And the runtimes on my computer were:

```
%timeit twoFreq(z, source_z, num, den, matrix, e)
```

> 1 loop, best of 3: 246 ms per loop

```
%timeit twoFreq_orig(z, source_z, num, den, matrix, e)
```

> 1 loop, best of 3: 344 ms per loop

It's approximatly 30% faster than your numpy-solution. But I think the numpy solution could be made a bit faster with clever usage of broadcasting. But nevertheless, most of the speedup I got was from omitting the signature: notice that you probably use C-contiguous arrays but you have given an arbitary ordering (so numba might be a bit slower depending on the computer architecture). Probably by defining `c16[::-1]` you'll get the same speed but generally just let numba infer the type, it will probably be as fast as it can be. Exception: You want different precision inputs for each variable (for example you want `z` to be `complex128` and `complex64`)

You will get an amazing speedup when your numpy solution runs out of memory (because your numpy solution is vectorized it will need much more RAM!) With `numb = 5000` the numba version was approximatly 3x faster than the numpy one.

---

## EDIT:

With clever broadcasting I mean that

```
np.conj(z[:,None]**(den-1)) * source_z[None, :]**(num)
```

is equal to

```
z1, z2 = np.meshgrid(source_z, np.conj(z))
z1**(num) * z2**(den-1)
```

but with the first variant you only have the power operation on `numb` elements whereas you have a `(numb, numb)` shaped array so you perform much more "power" operations than necessary (even though I guess for small arrays the result is probably mostly cached and not very expensive)

The version for numpy without `mgrid` (which produces the same result) looks like this:

```
def twoFreq_orig2(z, source_z, num, den, matrix, e):
    z1z2 = source_z[None,:]**(num) * np.conj(z)[:, None]**(den-1)
    M = (e ** ((num + den - 2) / 2.0)) * z1z2
    return np.sum(matrix * M, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response/help. Indeed I forgot to conjugate! Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "clever usage of broadcasting" for the pure Numpy implementation?

Comment: @jorgeh - I've edited some elaboration on the fact into the answer (last paragraph). But I had some deviations when I tried to insert this into your numpy-function so I abandoned that experiment and didn't want to mention it in fact it isn't possible. :-)

Comment: @jorgeh - I could get the not-mgrid version working and also included it into the answer. But I forgot that ``den`` and ``num`` are 2d arrays so there was actually only a little gain in speed.